# Contar registros de una tabla con jquery

Tags: jquery, table

como puedo contar los registros de una tabla id= "sal" el cual aparece dentro de un div id="resultados1", trato de hacer la validacion con el form. Necesito saber si no tiene registros la tabla me de un mensaje de alerta . Adjunto codigo

```
``<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="comp_sali.php" method="POST"  >



<button   type="submit" value="Generar Comprobante" id="add_sali" name="add_sali"  class="btn btn-info" style="width: 220px;">
          <i class="fas fa-print"></i> Generar Comprobante</button>
```

// el boton está dentro del formulario

````
```<div id="resultados1" class='col-md-12' ></div>
````

// Este es el script que deberia contar los registros de la tabla id="sal"

```
 function validateForm() {


       var nFilas = $("#sal tr").length;
       if ( nfilas == 0 ){
         alertify.alert("Atención","Primero seleccionar productos para entregar");
                  return false;
                 } 
       }

    </script>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿de dónde vienen los registros de la tabla?

Comment: de un modal que se muestra y luego con un boton en una columna selecciono los registros que se insertan en la tabla sal, la tabla con id ="sal" esta en otra pagina y aparece dentro del div =resultados1

Comment: los datos que se a través de ajax, se hace la consulta y trae todos los registros que yo puedo seleccionar  el successs function es  $("#resultados1").html(datos);

Comment: Perdon, los datos se traen a través de ajax y devuelve el success function  $("#resultados1").html(datos);

Comment: Si los traes por medio de Ajax, significa que los traes del servidor. Entonces lo correcto es organizar la respuesta de Ajax, para poder saber con facilidad si hay filas o no. La lógica que estás usando (de querer contar filas en una tabla que podría estar vacía) no es la más adecuada, deberías saberlo antes, sin tener que pasar a contar filas de algo que no existe. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Si lo que pasa es que la tabla sal  permite borrar los registros que se seleccionaron por error,  y si me queda vacia sin registros me queda el encabezado de la tabla y no me toma, me parece que el error esta en como consulta la cantidad de registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clave es pensar en lo que supone que una tabla esté vacía. ¿Está vacía la tabla que no tiene `<tr>`? Es posible, si no tienes encabezados `<th>`. ¿Pero y si los tienes? Para ello se me ocurre estructura una tabla correctamente, con su `<thead>` y su `<tbody>` y de esa manera contar los `<tr>` que pertenecen al `<tbody>` para saber la cantidad de registros que tenemos en la tabla.

En mi ejemplo puse dos tablas, una con registros y otra que no, y mediante una función cuento los registros de la tabla que le paso como parámetro para arrojar el mensaje de error o hacer lo que necesites en consecuencia.

```js
$(function () {
 if (existen_registros(miTabla1)) {
  console.log('La primera tabla tiene registros');
 }
 else {
  console.log('La primera tabla no tiene registros');
 }
 
 if (existen_registros(miTabla2)) {
  console.log('La segunda tabla tiene registros');
 }
 else {
  console.log('La segunda tabla no tiene registros');
 }
});

function existen_registros (tabla) {
  let filas = $(tabla).find('tbody tr').length;
  
  if(filas > 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="miTabla1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cabecera 1</th>
      <th>Cabecera 2</th>
      <th>Cabecera 3</th>
      <th>Cabecera 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dato 1</td>
      <td>Dato 2</td>
      <td>Dato 3</td>
      <td>Dato 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dato 1</td>
      <td>Dato 2</td>
      <td>Dato 3</td>
      <td>Dato 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dato 1</td>
      <td>Dato 2</td>
      <td>Dato 3</td>
      <td>Dato 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="miTabla2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cabecera 1</th>
      <th>Cabecera 2</th>
      <th>Cabecera 3</th>
      <th>Cabecera 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: El problema es que no ve la tabla id="sal", existe una forma de expresar que pertenece al div  resultados1 por ejemplo $("#resultados1").("#sal").(tbody tr")..Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no la ve? Pero si que existe forma. Date cuenta que los selectores de **JQuery** son como los selectores de **CSS**. Así que haciendo `$("#resultados1 #sal tbody tr").length` estarías seleccionando a los elementos `<tr>` que sean hijos de un `<tbody>`, que lo sea de un elemento con la id **#sal** que lo sea de un elemento con la id **resultados1**

Comment: Muchas gracias. de la única forma que funciono fue usando $("#resultados1 #sal tbody tr").length. . si lo hacia con #sal tbody tr no funcionaba, tal vez sea porque la tabla se encuentra en un div. No lo se, pero funcionó Gracias

Comment: La mejor manera de agradecer es votando positivo a la respuesta, además de como válida para que quede cerrada y la gente que la visita sepa que obtuvo solución ^^